# when I check a condition what tense should I use?

Tags: meaning, tense

this post (https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/did-you-finish-vs-have-you-finished.1189126/) gives these explanations about present perfect and simple past.

1. past ---->now = have you finished?
2. past ---->end of exercise<------now = did you finish?
3. Means have you finished (now or yet)? Implies they are nearly out of time.
4. Means did you finish (at all)? Implies that the students were out of time in the past.

My son and I made a deal, which is, when he finish his homework, he is allowed to hang out with his friend. no deadline.

Hours passed, he is trying walk out, what tense should I use?

Comment: Both are possible and idiomatic. As he starts to walk out: “Did you finish your homework?” OR “Have you finished your homework?” I think the latter is perhaps more likely.

Comment: Notice that “did you finish...” can imply here *“during the time you spent in your room, did you finish...”* so in that way it is after the “end of an exercise”.